# How to use "sudo npm" in Google Cloud Console?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have created a new project in Google Cloud Console, and have linked it to my github repo with source code in.

I can see the files have been cloned correctly when I goto the cloud console, and I need to install some dependencies to compile my code before I deploy it. I ran `npm install` fine, but I also need to do `bower install`, `typings install`, `gulp my-task` etc.

When I try to install bower by doing `npm install -g bower` I get an error telling me (correctly) that it needs to be run as admin, and doing `sudo npm install -g bower` gives me the error `sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to install those globally, since npm installs the same package regardless of if it's installed locally or globally. For instance, if you wanted to run gulp, even without installing it globally, you could do this: `node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` since all `npm install -g` does is places it in your path with a runnable script. (Well, it's a little more complex than that, but you _can_ run it without installing it globally.)

Comment: Asciinema demo: https://asciinema.org/a/3rkfu05vspocnga6n950x0rna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently you have nodejs installed ... so the following changes to root's env vars are needed ... as yourself execute following :

```
echo $NODE_PATH    #  use this value in a minute
```

As root edit its file  ~root/.bashrc and add this line

```
export NODE_PATH=value_from_above_echo
```

now identify PATH to reach node ... issue following as yourself

```
which node
```

similarly as root edit ~root/.bashrc and add this line

```
export PATH=value_of_dir_from_above_which:${PATH}
```

Once you have made these two changes to the root env vars then root can issue node and npm commands ... to engage changes either create fresh root shell session or as root source its ~/.bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```